# Parse Date differences between W7 and Server2012 R2

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

```
DateTime Date;
DateTime.TryParse("01.09.2015", (new CultureInfo("en-CA")), DateTimeStyles.None, out Date);
```

Windows 7 SP1 Result:

```
Date    {01.09.2015 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
Date    {01.09.2015 00:00:00}   System.DateTime
Day 1   int
DayOfWeek   Tuesday System.DayOfWeek
DayOfYear   244 int
Hour    0   int
Kind    Unspecified System.DateTimeKind
Millisecond 0   int
Minute  0   int
Month   9   int
Second  0   int
Ticks   635766624000000000  long
TimeOfDay   {00:00:00}  System.TimeSpan
Year    2015    int
```

Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Result:

```
Date    {1/9/2015 12:00:00 AM}  System.DateTime
Date    {1/9/2015 12:00:00 AM}  System.DateTime
Day 9   int
DayOfWeek   Friday  System.DayOfWeek
DayOfYear   9   int
Hour    0   int
Kind    Unspecified System.DateTimeKind
Millisecond 0   int
Minute  0   int
Month   1   int
Second  0   int
Ticks   635563584000000000  long
TimeOfDay   {00:00:00}  System.TimeSpan
Year    2015    int
```

Why are these differences for day and month ? Any patch needed ?

Comment: Hey @RolfS, my answer isn't helpful?

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.TryParse` uses [standard date and time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of supplied culture. Looks like this `en-CA` culture has different formats with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012.

Seems like Windows 7 using `dd/MM/yyyy` format and Windows Server 2012 using `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

This settings can change over .NET Framework version and/or OS version. Don't worry. If you want to parse your string exactly, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.TryParseExact.aspx) methods to supply exact format for your string.

```
string s = "01.09.2015";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-CA"),
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // 1 September 2015
}
```

or

```
string s = "01.09.2015";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MM.dd.yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-CA"),
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // 9 January 2015
}
```